# Discord.py error : [modal.py] Ignoring exception in modal <trainModal timeout=None children=1>: (modal.py:164)

Tags: python, mysql, discord.py

Appereantly this error has been bugging off to much lately for me.
It says it is ignoring an error but I get no intel on what the error is. And also it is almost impossible to debug it (for me at least).
So I check the code and everything seems correct to me. Here is the trainModal class where the error happens :

```py
        class trainModal(ui.Modal):
            def __init__(self):
                super().__init__(
                    title="Training Dialog",
                )
                self.amount = ui.TextInput(label="Amount", style=discord.TextStyle.short,
                                           placeholder="Integer", required=True, min_length=1)
                self.add_item(self.amount)

#I get input from a user through the modal ^^ 


            async def on_submit(self, interaction):
                await interaction.response.defer()
                user = interaction.user
                val = int(self.amount.value)
                troop_name = train_select.values[0]
                troop_name = troop_name.lower()

                troop = Troops[troop_name]
                cost = troop["cost"] * val
                train_time = troop["time"] * val

#I calucalate after submiting the values what db manipulation I should do.

                player = command_tree.db.get_player(user.id)
                if player.gold < cost:
                    return await interaction.followup.send(
                        f"You don't have enough gold to train {val} {troop_name}."
                    )

                msg: discord.WebhookMessage = await interaction.followup.send(
                    f"Training {self.amount} {troop_name} in `{train_time}` seconds.")
                await asyncio.sleep(train_time)

#I wait for time through asyncio.sleep and after it is done, the error kicks in and the part below is never executed.



                command_tree.db.update_player(user.id, +val, troop_name)
                command_tree.db.update_player(user.id, -cost, "gold")
                await msg.edit(
                    content=f"Trained {self.amount} {troop_name} for {emote.GOLD} {cost}"
                )
```

I don't find any syntax or anything like that in this piece of code. In docs the kwargs are supposed to be just like how I have them in the modal class, but the error keeps persisting no matter the changes. I opened a discussion in discord.py as well and waiting for a response. Any help from you as well , would be appreciated.